# Momentum operator in QM - scalar or vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, vectors, covariance

The momentum operator for one spatial dimension is $-i \hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ (which isn't a vector operator) but for 3 spatial dimensions is $-i\hbar\nabla$ which is a vector operator. So is it a vector or a scalar operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$, a scalar, is the *position space representation* of $\hat{p}_x$, the $x$ component of the momentum operator, a scalar. The momentum operator itself, $\hat{\textbf{p}}$, is a vector operator. The position space representation of $\hat{\textbf{p}}$ would be $-i\hbar \nabla$, a vector.

Again, the momentum operator is a vector operator. The components of the momentum operator are scalars operators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Shouldn't then be $-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}\hat{i}$ ?

Comment: Don’t have time for proper response. My answer is actually a little messed up. In differential geometry $\frac{d}{dx}$ is actually thought of as a vector not a scalar. Regardless, you don’t usually ever see $\frac{d}{dx}\hat{i}$ so I wouldn’t write that down. Maybe later I can give a more thorough correction

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas there is only one dimension so the direction is implicit. You don't need an explicit $\hat i$ since there is only one possible axis along which to travel.

Answer (score 14):

Momentum is a vector operator. Period.

When restricted to one-dimensional problems, momentum becomes a one-dimensional vector, which coincides with scalars in that space.

Comment: Shouldn't then be $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\hat{i}$ ? Thanks in advantage.

Comment: The difference doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually there is a remnant of orthogonal group in $R^1$ which is the parity inversion. $P$ is a *vector* operator with respect to it.